# Regex to select latest expression in math formula to change sign

Tags: java, regex, kotlin

I want to have a regex that can detect last math expression in order to change sign of that expression for example :

```
5 --> -5

-5 --> 5

5+2*cos(10) --> 5-2*cos(10)

5-cos(10+2) --> 5+cos(10+2)
```

I still couldn't create any regex that can match last expression. I created this regex `(\+[(cos|sin|tan)])+(.*[0-9]*.)` but it only select the last expression if there is a sin/cos or tan.

Comment: I think that regular expressions won't solve the whole problem. You need to build a tree repesenting all the operations to choose the last one.

Comment: hmm okay thank you. I thought maybe I'm missing some feature of regex that might help.

Comment: It will be a crazy thing to do, but the only regex way I see is to build a regex with alternatives matching and capturing various contexts and in the match evaluator part analyze the match structure and replace accordingly. A regex that probably handles all contexts is `(?:cos|sin|tan)\([^()]*\)|^(-)|^(\d)|([-+])`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks I'm not really obliged to follow regex I will try tree parsing.

Comment: Why regex? You can sort and take the last entry.

Comment: @Dominique could you elaborate more please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for being (incredibly) late to the party, but here's my solution:

```
String str = "5*10/2+cos(54/90)", regex = "(\\+|-)(?=(?:[a-zA-Z]*\\(.*?\\))|[0-9^*/]+$)";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = pat.matcher(str);
String r = "";
if(m.find())
{
    r = m.group(1).equals("+")?"-":"+";
}
str = str.replaceAll(regex, r);
System.out.println(str);
```

I'm using BlueJ as an IDE, btw.

Here's a live demo: **https://regex101.com/r/3EM9Ix/1**

## EXPLANATION

`(\\+|-)` selects the desired operator, '+' or '-'
`(?=(?:[a-zA-Z]*\\(.*?\\))|[0-9^*/]+$)` is the regex that checks if the operator is followed by either a function which has letters in it or just some more digits